# Are there 'closed' solution of Schroedinger equation?

Tags: wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, time-evolution

Are there closed solution for the wave function of schroedinger equation?

i mean solutions in the form $ \Psi (x,t)=  f(x-t,y,z,t) $

that are not given by infinite series.

For example for the 1+1D wave function there is the closed d'Alambert solution

$$ f(x-vt)+ f(x+vt) $$ where $v$ is the speed of the propagation of the wave.

Comment: Is there something you don't like about the usual answers to, say,  the infinite square well, the finite square well, the harmonic oscillator, or the hydrogen-like atom? Are you objecting to their being of multiple states? Because for each of these each state is exactly solvable.

Comment: how about the hydrogen wavefunctions ? http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/hydwf.html

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/103503/2451

Comment: Your nondispersive solution of the d'Alembertian does not solve the free Schroedinger equation. But the [dispersive Gaussian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_packet#Dispersive) does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any "nice" square-normalizable function $f(\textbf{x})$ can be a solution to the time-dependent Schrödinger equation at some point in time. To see this, consider the case of a time-independent Hamiltonian, and define the function

$$f(\textbf{x},t)\equiv e^{-iHt/\hbar}f(\textbf{x}).$$

It is clear from the functional form that $i\hbar\partial f(\textbf{x},t)/\partial t=Hf(\textbf{x},t)$, so that it is a solution to the Schrödinger Equation. If the Hamiltonian is time-dependent, then we can use Dyson's trick and define

$$f(\textbf{x},t)\equiv\text{Texp}\left[-\frac{i}{\hbar}\int_{0}^{t}H(t')\mathrm{d}t'\right]f(\textbf{x}),$$

where $\text{Texp}$ is the time-ordered exponential, the details of which I won't go into.

This is about as closed form as a solution to the Schrödinger equation gets, until you specify a potential.

Comment: I think you left $f({\bf x})$ in the rhs of your second equation. And your $\rm Texp$ seems to be exactly the type of 'infinite series'  that OP wants to avoid.

Comment: Yes, thank you for pointing that out! As for the infinite series, yes, defining $\text{Texp}$ is a bit of a cop-out but, as I stated, this is about as closed-form you can get without specifying the exact problem. If we could get any closed-form, then finite-time QFT would be a LOT easier.