# Dyson series for Hamiltonian with $c$-number commutator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, commutator, time-evolution

I am trying to derive the evolution operator for a time dependent Hamiltonian which satisfies the commutator
$$[H(t_1), H(t_2)]=I f(t_1,t_2)$$
Where $I$ is the identity operator, and $f(t_1,t_2)$ is an arbitrary function of the time parameters which maps to the complex numbers.

I am aware of a derivation which uses the [Magnus expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnus_expansion), an exponential operator expansion in nested commutators of the Hamiltonian, but I am trying to derive it using the Dyson series expansion.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/103503/2451