# Understanding of the expressions for vacuum-to-vacuum transition amplitude

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, path-integral, boundary-conditions

Consider the amplitude $$Z=\big\langle 0\big|\exp\big(-\frac{iHT}{\hbar}\big)\big|0\big\rangle.$$ This is same as $$Z=\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty} dq\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty} dq^\prime\langle 0|q^\prime\rangle\langle q^\prime|e^{-iHT/\hbar}|q\rangle\langle q|0\rangle=\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty} dq\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}dq^\prime~ \phi^*_0(q^\prime)\phi_0(q)K(q,t;q^\prime,t^\prime)$$ where $\phi_0(q)$ is the position space wavefunction for the ground state $|0\rangle$ evaluated at $q$ and $$K(q,t;q^\prime,t^\prime)\equiv \langle q^\prime|e^{-iHT/\hbar}|q\rangle=\int_{q(t)=q}^{q(t^\prime)=q^\prime} Dq(t) \exp\Big[i\int_0^Tdt(\frac{1}{2}m\dot{q}^2-V(q)\Big].$$ This integral has informations about the ground state i.e., we need the ground state wavefunction to evaluate this.

But $Z$ has an alternative expression in terms of a path-integral as $$Z=\int Dq(t) \exp\Big[\frac{i}{\hbar}\int_0^Tdt(\frac{1}{2}m\dot{q}^2-V(q)\Big].$$ Unlike the first expression of $Z$, from the second expression has anything to do with the ground state or knows about the ground state. I find it amusing that the second relation apparently oblivious to the ground state?

- Is there any boundary condition for $q(0)$ and $q(T)$ in $\int Dq(t)$? This is not clear. Now, we are not evaluating $\big\langle q_i\big|\exp\big(-\frac{iHT}{\hbar}\big)\big|q_f\big\rangle$. So I see no reason of fixing anything.
- It is possible to derive the second relation from the first or the first relation from the second?
- Is there a similar path integral expression for $\big\langle f\big|\exp\big(-\frac{iHT}{\hbar}\big)\big|i\big\rangle$ where $i$ and $f$ are arbitrary initial or final state?

Comment: Second expression is under specified. It begs  to ask what paths you are integrating over. First expression is a special case of the last expression.

Comment: Yes. I am asking how to relate these two expressions of $Z$.

Comment: If you see answer of Qmechanic for your other recent question. For second expression to make sense (even at Physicists level of rigour), you have to specify what boundary conditions paths satisfy. If you are integrating over all paths without constraints, it just means you are evaluating $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}dq_f\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}dq_i\langle q_f| e_{}^{- i H t}|q_i\rangle$ for whatever purpose you are after.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/409907/2451 and links therein.

Comment: @Sunyam What boundary condition do you suggest here? In the previous answer I wasn't evaluating vacuum to vacuum amplitude but amplitude of going from $|q_i\rangle$ to $|q_f\rangle$. There boundary conditions would be $q(0)=q_i$ and $q_f=q(T)$.  But I agree that as a path integral second expression is not meaningful unless we have a boundary condition. But what boundary condition would appear here and how?

Comment: @mithunsengupta123 It's a good idea if you can construct coordinate space path integral (for transition amplitudes and partition function and vaccum-vaccum amplitudes etc) starting from Trotter formula, somehow I feel that that can clear up all your questions.

Answer (score 1):

Let's be more careful:
$$
K(q,t|q^\prime, t^\prime)=\int_{q(t)=q}^{q(t^\prime)=q^\prime} Dq(t) \exp\Big[i\int_0^Tdt(\frac{1}{2}m\dot{q}^2-V(q)\Big].
$$
In this integral you need integrate over all continuous trajectories with boundary conditions at $t$ and $t^\prime$: $q(t)=q$ and $q^\prime(t^\prime)=q^\prime$.

Using $K$ you easily can calculate evaluation of wave function:

$$
\psi(q,t) =\int dq^\prime K(q,t|q^\prime, t^\prime)\psi(q^\prime, t^\prime)
$$

So for amplitude you obtain:

$$
\big\langle \psi^\prime(t)\big|\psi(t)\big\rangle
=
\big\langle \psi^\prime(t)\big|\exp\big(-\frac{iH(t-t^\prime)}{\hbar}\big)\big|\psi(t^\prime)\big\rangle
=
\int dq \underbrace{\int dq^\prime K(q,t|q^\prime, t^\prime)\psi(q^\prime, t^\prime)}_{\psi(q,t)}(\psi^\prime(q,t))^*
$$

For vacum-vacum amplitude you need put ground state wave function.

For partition function (which usually denoted as Z):

$$
Z =Tr_{\mathcal{H}}e^{-iHT/\hbar} = 
\int dq \big\langle q\big|\exp\big(-\frac{iHT}{\hbar}\big)\big|q\big\rangle
=\int dq\int_{q(0)=q}^{q(T)=q} Dq(t) \exp\Big[i\int_0^Tdt(\frac{1}{2}m\dot{q}^2-V(q)\Big]
$$

Useful reference [Path Integral](http://hitoshi.berkeley.edu/221a/pathintegral.pdf)

Also I recommend you read appendix in [book by Joseph Polchinski](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521672279)

Comment: I made made a small edit. Please see if you are okay with it. If not, revert it.

Comment: It's okay. You more careful wrote boundary conditions.

Comment: I updated my answer.

Comment: So basically $Z=\int dq \int dq^\prime \psi^{\prime}_0(q^\prime)\psi^*_0(q)K(q,t;q^\prime,t^\prime)$. How does that reduce to my expression for $Z$? This was my second question.

Comment: Could you be more concrete?, I can't understand question:(

Comment: I updated answer

Comment: Is my expression for $Z$ in terms of a path-integral (in the question) same as your expression for $K$? Do you agree with my expression of Z?

Comment: It is not correct.  K is heat kernel. K define how wave function evaluate

Comment: Maybe you confused with partition function, which usually indicated as Z

Comment: I am after the vacuum-to-vacuum transition amplitude, which is $Z$ or the partition function. Do you agree with my expression of Z? I took it from Zee's QFT. I have shown how Z and K are related.

Comment: I updated answer, I included information about partition function

Comment: I once more updated answer

Comment: I think Zee was very sloppy in this chapter:(