# Utility of the time-ordered exponential

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, operators, mathematical-physics, time-evolution

Is the time-ordered exponential

$$ \mathcal{T}\exp\left\{-i\int_{t_0}^tdt'V(t')\right\}\tag{1} $$

just a mnemonic device for the series

$$
\begin{aligned} 1 + (-i)\int_{t_0}^tdt_1 \, V(t_1) +{} &
(-i)^2\int_{t_0}^t dt_1 \int_{t_0}^{t_1}dt_2 \, V(t_1)V(t_2)
\\&+(-i)^3 \int_{t_0}^t dt_1 \int_{t_0}^{t_1} dt_2 \int_{t_0}^{t_2} dt_3 \, V(t_1)V(t_2)V(t_3)+ \cdots
\end{aligned}\tag{2}
$$

or is there more to it?

The series one gets when expanding the time-ordered exponential is full of time-ordered products and not useful as such. Are there other advantages to the first expression except for compactness?

Comment: Another representation that I find useful is that, if you call $h_{t_2\leftarrow t_1}$ the evolution from time $t_1$ to $t_1$, then the time ordered exponential is $\lim_{\epsilon\to0}\prod_{k=1}^{1/\epsilon}h_{t -(k-1)\epsilon \delta\leftarrow t -k\epsilon \delta}$, having called $\delta = t-t_0$. I particularly like this representation for Wilson lines because it makes it easier to prove the transformation properties. Might this be useful for you?

Answer (score 2):

The [time-ordered exponential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_exponential) (1) is the unique solution $U(t,t_0)$ to the first-order initial value problem:
$$ i\frac{d}{dt} U(t,t_0)~=~V(t)U(t,t_0), \qquad t~\geq ~t_0, \qquad U(t_0,t_0)~=~\mathbb{1}. \tag{A} $$
The [ODE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_differential_equation) (A) is sometimes useful. See also [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/103503/2451) related Phys.SE post.

Comment: Well, that is exactly why I’m asking.  The way to prove that (1) is a solution to (A) is actually to prove that (1) = (2) and then showing by explicit differentiation that (2) is a solution to (A). Seems kinda cumbersome to remember (1) and how to get to (2), I’d rather just remember (2).