# Generator of time shift when the Hamiltonian is time dependent

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, schroedinger-equation, time-evolution, unitarity

Let's consider the unitary group $\hat{S_{\tau}^†}$ such that :$$\hat{S^†_{\tau}}|\psi(t)\rangle=|\psi(t-\tau)\rangle$$
Since we know that:
$$\hat{U}(t,t_0)|\psi(t_0)\rangle=|\psi(t)\rangle$$
Where ${U}(t,t_0)$ is the time evolution operator, we can conclude that:
$$\hat{S^†_{\tau}}=U(t-\tau,t).$$
Now we also know that $\hat{U}$ solves:
$$iℏ\partial_t\hat{U}=\hat{H}\hat{U}$$
So that if $\hat{H}$ does not depend explicitly on time we have:
$$U(t,t_0)=e^{-\frac{i}{ℏ}(t-t_0)\hat{H}} (*)$$
Hence:
$$\hat{S^†_{\tau}}=U(t-\tau,t)=e^{\frac{i}{ℏ}\tau\hat{H}}$$
$$\hat{S_{\tau}}=e^{-\frac{i}{ℏ}\tau\hat{H}}$$
And we can surely say that $\hat{H}$ is the generator of time translations.
Now what happens when $\hat{H}$ has an explicit dependence on time ? Equation $(*)$ no longer holds and I am not confident in saying that $\hat{H}$ is still the generator of the group $\hat{S_{\tau}}$. The book I'm reading doesn't distinguish between these two cases. Is it because it only considers infinitesimal translations?

Comment: This depends on how you define "generator". In the case where $H$ depends on time, Stone's theorem does not hold anymore.

Comment: Is it possible to define a generator without referring to Stone's theorem ?

Comment: What do you mean with "generator"?

Comment: Review time-ordered exponentials. It should become evident to you what "generator", an infelicitous term here, represents.

Comment: [Linked](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/452236/utility-of-the-time-ordered-exponential) and [also](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/774543/question-about-the-time-ordered-exponential-operator). "Generator" is shorthand for "Agent", as in sufficient determinator. You may think of an infinity of generators, one for each time instant.

Comment: The instantaneous generator of infinitesimal time translations at time $t$ is $H(t)$. There is no single generator for all time because a time-dependent evolution doesn't enjoy time-translation invariance. Accordingly, time evolution can't be generated by a single operator in the sense of Lie algebras and groups (i.e. **your $\hat{S}$ guy is no longer a [semi]group**). Most people wouldn't use the term "generator" in this context because of that.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the solution of:
$$i\hbar{\partial\over \partial t}\mathcal U(t,t_0)=H\mathcal U(t,t_0).$$
If the Hamiltonian is time dependent and if it commutes with itself at different times,
$$[H(t),H(t^\prime)]=0,\;t\neq t^\prime.$$
Then the time development is given by:
$$\mathcal U(t,t_0)=e^{-{i\over\hbar}\int_{t_0}^t H(t^\prime)\;dt^\prime}.$$
If the Hamiltonian does not commute with itself at different times:
$$[H(t),H(t^\prime)]\neq 0,$$
then the time development operator is given as:
$$\mathcal U(t,t_0)=1+\sum\limits_{n=1}\limits^{\infty}\bigg({-i\over\hbar}\bigg)^n\int_{t_0}^t\;dt_1\int_{t_0}^{t_1}\;dt_2\cdots \int_{t_0}^{t_{n-1}}\;dt_n\;H(t_1)H(t_2)\cdots H(t_n). $$
This last result is known as a *Dyson series* and is important in quantum field theory.