# What's the minimum condition for time evolution operator to be written as $U(t,t_0)=e^{-\frac{i}{\hbar} \int_{t_0}^t H(t') dt'}$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, time-evolution

Is $\frac{d }{dt} e^{H(t)}=H(t)' e^{H(t)}$ the minimum condition for time evolution operator to be written as $U(t,t_0)=e^{-\frac{i}{\hbar} \int_{t_0}^t H(t') dt'}$?

Further, what's the minimum condition for time evolution operator to be written as $U(t,t_0)=e^{-\frac{i}{\hbar} E_n(t-t_0)}$?(Actually, what I think I meant was $U(t,t_0)=[$ matrix with diagonal element of $e^{-\frac{i}{\hbar} E_n(t-t_0)}]$)? The same as the previous question, or something extra?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/103503/2451

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **most general** "solution" to the Schrödinger equation

$$
i\hbar\frac{d|\psi\rangle}{dt} = \hat{H}(t)|\psi\rangle
$$

is given by the time ordered exponential

$$
| \psi(t) \rangle = \mathcal{T}\left\{ e^{-\frac{i}{\hbar}\int_{t_0}^{t} dt'\  \hat{H}(t') } \right\} | \psi(t_0)\rangle,
$$

where $\mathcal{T}$ is the time ordering operator. That is, the general time evolution operator is

$$
U(t, t_0) = \mathcal{T}\left\{ e^{-\frac{i}{\hbar}\int_{t_0}^{t} dt'\  \hat{H}(t') } \right\}.
$$

Therefore, the minimum condition to be able to "remove" the time ordering symbol and hence obtain

$$ 
U(t, t_0)= e^{-\frac{i}{\hbar}\int_{t_0}^{t} dt'\  \hat{H}(t') } 
$$

is that the **hamiltonian commutes with itself at any two times**. That is, the condition is given by

$$
U(t, t_0)= e^{-\frac{i}{\hbar}\int_{t_0}^{t} dt'\  \hat{H}(t') } 
 \iff [H(t), H(t')]=0\ \ \ \forall t, t'.
$$