# How do you solve the Schroedinger Equation for the time evolution operator?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, hamiltonian, time-evolution

The equation below is the time-dependent Schroedinger equation for the time evolution operator $U$.

$$i\hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial t}U(t,t_0) = HU(t,t_0).$$

According to my prof. this can be solved as a differential equation:

(my attempt) Assume both U and H are dependent on $t$. Let
$ \frac{\partial U}{\partial t} = U'$ ($t_0$ is not a variable).
$$ U' = -\frac{i}{\hbar} HU $$
$$\frac{U'}{U} = -\frac{i}{\hbar} H $$
$$ \int \frac{U'}{U} dt = -\frac{i}{\hbar} \int H dt$$
Use standard integral
$$\ln |U| = -\frac{i}{\hbar} \int H dt $$

This works provided the unitary operator can be treated as a function. Can someone explain:

1. whether it can be and why it can.
2. if it can't, why it can't, and how the actual proof should go.

Comment: Hello Abe Jacob. This StackExchange article discusses the Solution of the time dependent Schrödinger equation in a very general framework https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/103503/273635 maybe this could give you a bit of an overview.

Comment: U is a matrix, not a number. You can't write something like $\frac{U'}{U}$, It's ambiguous. It should be either $U^{-1}U'$ or $U'U^{-1}$

Comment: @KP99 I know, but I couldn't see another way to solve the ODE. The last line of writing above my 2 questions addresses this.