# Why is the time evolution operator not Weyl ordered?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, commutator, time-evolution, wick-theorem

I am reading the book "Structural Aspects of Quantum Field Theory" by Gerhard Grensing. After introducing the Weyl formalism of symmetrizing the coordinates and momenta, he starts with a section on "Generalized Weyl Formalism" and says:

> There are operators of fundamental importance that are definitely not Weyl ordered;
> they also do not belong to one of the known modified ordering schemes. Relevant examples include the time evolution operator $\hat U(t)=\exp(-i\hat H t/\hbar)$, **where the Hamiltonian operator is assumed to be Weyl ordered** or its imaginary time analogue, $\hat U(\beta)=\exp(-\beta \hat H)$. It is thus of fundamental importance that the Weyl Formalism be generalized.

I don't understand the boldfaced line above. If we have already Weyl ordered the Hamiltonian, won't an expansion of the exponential guarantee that the evolution operator is also Weyl ordered. I guess the problems start when we have to write a time ordered exponential i.e. $[\hat H(t),\hat H(t')]\neq 0$, but I do not understand how.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

1. The defining formulation of the time evolution operator $U(t_2,t_1)$ is indeed time-ordered wrt. the Hamiltonian $H(t)$, cf e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/103503/2451) Phys.SE post.
2. If the Hamiltonian $H(t)$ itself has a different operator ordering (say e.g. Weyl-ordering or normal-ordering), then one may in principle$^1$ be able to bring $U(t_2,t_1)$ to the different operator ordering via a nested Wick theorem, cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/24157/2451) Phys.SE post.
3. More generally, one may in principle$^1$ rewrite an operator in one operator ordering into another operator ordering via Wick-like theorems. It should be stressed that applying [Wick's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wick%27s_theorem) does not change an operator, it only re-organizes its terms.

--

$^1$ The transcription may fail due to divergent terms.

Comment: So, this means that the Weyl formalism does not give a consistent quantisation procedure, since operators like $\hat U$ can not be uniquely ordered using Weyl's ordering? Is that correct?

Comment: $\uparrow $ No.

Comment: Okay. Can you please explain what you mean by being able to bring $U(t_2,t_1)$ to a different operator, and its relation to the my original question? I do not know about Wick's theorem.

Comment: $U(t_2,t_1)$ is what $U(t_2,t_1)$ is, and is not changed.